# Wesite design/programming considerations to protect children on a social network website?

Tags: social-networking

I'm developing a social network site its currently in the planning stages. One of the concerns is its likely the largest group of users are likely to be children. 
Users will be able to post content and comment on other users posts.
**What can I do to reduce the risks of** :-

1. Bullying
2. stalking
3. Users disclosing contact details publicly
4. Users disclosing other personal information publicly
5. List item
6. (other suggestions, please)

**Note:** I'm also trying to **avoid having to do too much moderation manually** so I'm looking for suggestions to incorporate into the site design to reduce the moderation overhead and best protect users.

In regards to 3 and email address, I realize of course some form of filtering is required on posts and comments but as we all know its so easy to circumvent by doing something like myname[at]hotmail.com, etc

**Edit:** 
of course this is programming related, I'm looking for a programming/design solutions to a social problem. please reopen this question.
Even SO and facebook, etc use tools and design decisions to reduce user abuse. So clearly this is a programming/website design question

To those who voted to close this I am not looking for a purely programmatic solution, I'm looking for ways programmers/website designers can reduce the need for manual moderation through good design, filtering, etc.

Comment: I don't this can be done programatically, I think this can only be accomplished by moderation.

Comment: @Zoidberg, To say this can not be done programatically is incorrect, clearly there are steps such as filtering user input, adding report abuse buttons to aid moderation. This is programming related, so kindly reopen it. Over SO user have already suggested design solutions which clearly demonstrates there are measures that can and should be taken.

Comment: Sorry that the question was closed, I also believe it shouldn't have been closed. Moderation requires more programming to enable the site to be moderated effectively, this is definitely related to programming.

Comment: Thanks Waleed, I don't think everybody understood I was looking for methods to reduce manual moderation rather than replace it. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you'll have to design the site so that you count for moderators (ie. some members should be chosen to act as moderators to delete the bad content and punish the violators by temporarily suspending or even deleting their accounts, depending on the severity of the violation). Also users should be able to report violations (like offensive posts, inappropriate avatars .. etc), those reports should be examined by a moderator so you have to design your application to allow this to happen (ie. the moderator should be alerted when a post is reported)

Comment: Another way is that if a post is reported by many users (let's say 3 or 5 users), it get deleted automatically (this is done on stackoverflow by the way). You could also give points to users based on the accuracy of their reporting (you also have to account for annoying users who will report any posts that they don't agree with, the points system should solve this problem and users who abuse the system shouldn't be able to report, but this is should be done silently, ie. let them report the posts but just ignore their report if they have a bad history of reports, e.g. too many wrong reports)

Comment: If you allow the posts to be voted up or down, you may hide the post if it gets too many down-votes. Every approach of those has each advantages and disadvantages, there's really no one way to do this. Websites handle moderation is many different ways, try to have a look on the popular websites and see how they implement this to get some ideas. Wish you good luck.

Comment: "I don't think everybody understood I was looking for methods to reduce manual moderation rather than replace it. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough." .. No, it's just because it's not a technical question, for many users here if the question is not about a programming language, then it should be closed. I got many questions like this one closed. It seems questions related to the application architecture are not allowed here.

Comment: @ Waleed Eissa, great thanks for you ideas, I was thinking in regards to Avatars to limiting them to site provided content (with only limited customization allowed) and/or user uploaded avatars have to be approved before they're publicly visible.

Answer (score 3):

Technological measures are generally ineffective at solving these sorts of social problems. Manual moderation is pretty much the only really big useful thing you can do.

Successful sites of this nature tend to leverage the community to help with the task of moderation, by recruiting volunteer moderators from the more devoted regulars and/or providing post voting / flagging mechanisms (e.g. Stack Overflow).

Comment: @moonshadow, yes I agree the a purely programming approach would not be a solution, but as you know SO leverages community support to moderate this site and is part of the website design to have a self regulated community, these are the some of types of mechanisms I'm looking for as an aid to moderation not a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't allow 'dislike' or vote down style 'voting'. Bullying *will* still occur in text. That is life and will likely require manual moderation even if you filter abusive words.
2. Default to private profiles. You can't stalk someone you're not friends with as you can't see their info.
3. No suggestion as this is a very difficult, if not impossible problem. You could take simple steps of filtering email addresses out as they're easily identifiable but there are always work-around's and there's much more personal info than email addresses.
4. See above.

Ultimately a site like this requires manual moderation if it is going to be a friendly place for children to visit online

Comment: Thanks Dolbz, agree with 1st point, I also considered no downvoting below zero. and the remaining points. maybe my question wasn't clear I'm not looking to completely do away with manual moderation, just design considerations to reduce the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do to protect children from abuse of your site is to never go public with it in the first place.

That's not what you wanted to hear. But when you set up any kind of social whatzit site, the question is not if it will be abused, but when. And when that happens, you won't have a chance to be concerned about children because you'll be busy fighting legal battles that threaten to sue your pants off and throw you in the slammer.

To try to be positive, the second best thing you can do is rigorously filter who gets membership on your site. Also, I see no way to get around the requirement for heavy monitoring and moderation.

Comment: Nice answer!  Control who can sign up, and change how you spread the word.  Instead of spreading it on the internet (the likely place your going to find creeps), perhaps it can be done through a school bulletin or something.  Perhaps schools would jump at this given the prospect of getting children off facebook and other dangerous sites, and onto a safer social network.

Comment: @ Carl Smotricz, Not worried about law suits, just trying to be responsible. As you probably already know facebook, Myspace are regularly criticized for not doing enough to protect children. I'm simply looking for design considerations so I can work on preventative measures. Not sure how I'd go about filtering membership, maybe only using openID but that is probably to restrictive for the market.

Comment: With all respect, I think the suggestion to try to filter members is unrealistic. The internet is an anonymous world, how can you do that? He's talking about users misbehaving on the site, how will you anticipate the bad behavior of the users in advance? Even if this was possible somehow, it would mean he would have to work all day long to filter those members, probably with the help of a few other people if the site gets popular.

Comment: Filtering members is utterly feasible, if the operator is willing to go to the effort. Other social networking sites are successfully filtering members. Example: StudiVZ, a German Facebook ripoff (there have been some legal battles) limits membership to real, honest-to-god students, or at least tries to. I think they require certified physical ID for registration. It's an effort to check, but works (mostly).

Comment: This kind on filtering is of course simply based on the principle that people who rightly belong in your member set pose no threat to each other, so the aim is to keep creepy old perverts out. If you don't restrict age, sex and social group then filtering becomes more difficult, admittedly.

Comment: What remains in that case is to de-select people unwilling to surrender their own (validated) identity, people unwilling to enter a legal signed contract (guardian sig for kids) or people unwilling to pay a reasonable fee. Those filters keep *some* riff-raff out, though not all. This is why I am so pessimistic about the whole thing in the first place.

Comment: @ Carl, Yes ideally on the site I would prefer some degree of membership filtering but really wouldn't know how to practically do that. SMS text confirmation springs to mind but I'm not sure whether that form of check accomplishes anything. Requiring a school ID is possible and will be considered. thanks